# Hunt for Lua 4.1 alpha

Tags: lua

I`m helping with developing a multiplayer mod for a quite old game, Far Cry. I would like to compile the lua code, but the game uses version 4.1(alpha), which I can't find anywhere.

Comment: Indeed, in the [official Lua site](http://www.lua.org/versions.html) there is no version Lua 4.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[lua-4.1-alpha.tar.gz](http://www.lua.org/work/old/lua-4.1-alpha.tar.gz) is now available at http://www.lua.org/work/old/ , the repository of old pre-releases of Lua, for historical interest.

This tarball is exactly the one [announced](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2001-07/msg00178.html) in Jul 2001.

Lua 4.1 was never released: it evolved to Lua 5.0.

Comment: You just dug it up and added it for the OP? Nice one.

Comment: @Deduplicator, yes.

Comment: @lhf - Please visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055602/looking-for-the-lua-4-1-alpha-manual)

Comment: @Egor, the Lua 4.1 manual was never released. But see https://github.com/lua/lua/releases/tag/v4.1-alpha