# Looking for the Lua 4.1-alpha manual

Tags: lua, manual

It seems to be as much of a unicorn as the source code itself. Can't find it on the official Lua page or google. Anyone who still has it?

The manual included with the 4.1 source code is the 4.0 version( the date matches Lua 4.0 release ). I saw someone mentioning a 4.1 version of it here:
http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2001-07/msg00187.html

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57780432/1847592)

Comment: The one inside is still for version 4.0

Comment: Yes, the title of the manual is 4.0, but `lua.h` contains line `#define LUA_VERSION "Lua 4.1 (alpha)"`

Comment: The date on the manual file is the same as the Lua 4.0 release so that's not it. A 4.1 version has to exist as it was mentioned here:
http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2001-07/msg00187.html

Comment: Indeed.  You should ask @lhf about getting the 4.1 manual.

Comment: The Lua 4.1 manual was never released. But see https://github.com/lua/lua/releases/tag/v4.1-alpha